# Uploading multiple forms using FormData and a single XMLHttpRequest with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, form-data

Let's say I have two forms of the same structure but having different values at the end. I'd like to submit both of them using FormData and a single XMLHttpRequest request. I was trying to add another FormData object or an additional array but the result is an empty response so far.

HTML

```
<!-- first form -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/" >
  <input type="hidden" name="entity" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
  <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />
</form>

<!-- second form -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/" >
  <input type="hidden" name="entity" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
  <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var a = new FormData(); // using additional FormData object
var b = [];             // using an array
for(var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++){
  var form = document.forms[i];
  var data = new FormData(form);
  if(typeof form['file'] !== 'undefined'){
    for(var j=0; j<form['file'].files.length; j++){
      data.append('file[]', form['file'].files[j]);
    }
  }
  a.append(i, JSON.stringify(data)); // or a.append(i, data);
  b[i] = JSON.stringify(data);       // or b[i] = data;

}
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "ajax.php";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
  if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
xhr.send(a); // or xhr.send(b);
```

PHP

```
echo json_encode(array_merge($_GET, $_POST, $_FILES));
// or
print_r(array_merge($_GET, $_POST, $_FILES));
```

Comment: @KevinB Have you noticed the commented part(s) next to that and statement? Since I couldn't make it work I was trying all the (non)sense things. I hope you're happy after your downvote!

Comment: i mean, yeah, none of those make sense, and the documentation makes it pretty clear what could be passed into that method. Not quite sure why those were even attempted, [given the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several problems there.
One of the problems is that the name of your input is `file[]` and not `file`, so you need to use that name. The other problem is that you can't use `JSON.stringify` if you want to post files to the server.

Check the change I did to your code, it will do what you are looking for:

```js
var a = new FormData(); // using additional FormData object
var b = [];             // using an array
for(var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++){
    var form = document.forms[i];
    var data = new FormData(form);
    var formValues = data.entries()
    while (!(ent = formValues.next()).done) {

        // Note the change here 
        a.append(`${ent.value[0]}[]`, ent.value[1])
    }
}
// here a will include all the data from all of your forms.
```

```html
<!-- first form -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/" >
  <input type="hidden" name="entity" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
  <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />
</form>

<!-- second form -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/" >
  <input type="hidden" name="entity" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
  <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />
</form>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time. I'm still getting only one array. However, all uploaded files (from both forms) are here but as I can see, values of the second form are overwriting values of the first form; in other words I'm not getting two arrays.

Comment: You will never get two arrays because the names of your fields are the same, because they are overriden on the backend. I'll update the answer so you can have two arrays in the backend.

Comment: Check the change inside the while

Comment: Thanks a million! :) Now I'll try to add the other form elements like select box, radio and checkbox arrays. I hope it's gonna be ok.